# I don't have the apple ID on my iPod so I cannot delete iCloud?

Tags: icloud, ipod-touch, apple-id

So I bought my iPod from someone, and their iCloud account is still on here, which means the pictures I take and everything, they can see. I just noticed this and I tried to delete it, but it asks me to put in a password to turn off "find my iphone" and I do not have that password because it is someone else's iCloud account.

Comment: I suggest you try a factory reset on the iPod from iTunes, if you haven't already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

Your device is most likely Activation Locked. In order to remove the previous owner's Apple ID, you should try to get in contact with them and arrange to have them remove their ID from the device.

Activation Lock is an anti-theft feature, so if you do a factory restore in iTunes, you will be prompted for the previous owners Apple ID password when the device activates during initial set up. At this point you won't be able to use the device anymore.

Here are some Apple knowledge base articles that explain Activation Lock in a little more detail:

iCloud: Activation Lock: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13695

iCloud: Find My iPhone Activation Lock in iOS 7: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818